# DeadlineExceededErrors with GAE/Google API refreshing access token

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, google-calendar-api

Over the last few days I have been encountering DeadlineExceededErrors in my GAE app that interacts with the Google Calendar API. As far as I know these errors have been sporadic; I was not given these errors last night, but was during yesterday during the day and now this morning. I am **not** getting these errors when I run on the local dev environment, which makes me wonder what is going on with the GAE servers to cause this issue and how I can fix it.

I tried setting my urlFetch deadline to 45-60 but it didn't make a difference. I also tried building an HTTP object with a high timeout, but it didn't matter. The log looks like this:

```
2013-06-07 11:21:06.079 make: Got type <class 'google.appengine.api.datastore_types.Blob'>
I 2013-06-07 11:21:06.081 validate: Got type <class 'oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials'>
I 2013-06-07 11:21:06.086 make: Got type <class 'google.appengine.api.datastore_types.Blob'>
I 2013-06-07 11:21:06.087 validate: Got type <class 'oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials'>
I 2013-06-07 11:21:06.093 make: Got type <class 'google.appengine.api.datastore_types.Blob'>
I 2013-06-07 11:21:06.093 validate: Got type <class 'oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials'>
I 2013-06-07 11:21:06.094 URL being requested: https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest?userIp=99.19.70.243
I 2013-06-07 11:21:06.153 URL being requested: https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?alt=json
I 2013-06-07 11:21:06.201 Refreshing due to a 401
I 2013-06-07 11:21:06.207 make: Got type <class 'google.appengine.api.datastore_types.Blob'>
I 2013-06-07 11:21:06.208 validate: Got type <class 'oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials'>
I 2013-06-07 11:21:06.208 Refreshing access_token
E 2013-06-07 11:21:15.989 Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token Traceback (most recent call last): File "/py
```

Why is it choking on the refresh process now?

Edit: I should add that my app interacts with the Facebook API as well and I am not receiving DEEs for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may have been due to this issue?

> The problem with Google App Engine URL Fetch service to Google
>   Accounts authentication endpoints was resolved as of 5:15 PM
>   US/Pacific on June 7, 2013. We apologize for the inconvenience and
>   thank you for your patience and continued support. Please rest assured
>   that system reliability is a top priority at Google, and we are making
>   continuous improvements to make our systems better.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine-downtime-notify/TqKVL9TNq2A